# Type of Transaction manager J2EE application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, transactions

I have Confusion regarding Transaction manager used.
Below are few Transaction Manger which I know:
-Hibernate Transaction Manager
-JPA Transaction manager
-JDBC Transaction manger
-JTA Transaction Manger

In which case I can use Above transaction manager and how they work or differ from each other ..

And how UserTranasction and Transaction Manger of Application server plays any role in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your project can have container managed transaction or application managed transaction.

Container managed is when your server (jboss, glassfish, etc) that has JTA handles the transaction, that is the default behavior.

Application managed is when your project handles the transaction. You can use the UserManagerTransaction that will give you control over the transaction methods or you can use "*JPA programmatic transactions*" (I just invented this term).

You can create a transaction programmatic transaction by doing entityManager.getTransaction().begin(). You can use the Hibernate transaction, that is the same of the Hibernate transaction.

With Hibernate transaction you will be accessing all Hibernate functions that do not belong to the JPA Spec.

Comment: we define 2 manger in hibernate.cfg file "transaction.manager_lookup_class" this property and 2nd through spring "<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>" so how they are related to each other .and one declaration is sufficient or both is needed for transaction...
What is the difference in using Hbernate transaction manager and jdbc transaction manager

Comment: As far that I know, JDBC transaction managed is when you work with raw JDBC.

Comment: what abt this:we define 2 manger in hibernate.cfg file "transaction.manager_lookup_class" this property and 2nd through spring "<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" /> </bean>" so how they are related to each other